# Getting the first row of the element from an array

Tags: apache-spark-2.0

I want to get the first row from a spark 2 dataset..the dataset is as follow:

```
|arrayValue                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1.47527718E12, 134535353E12]                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I used below codes to acess the tow values

```
double training_point = (double) ratios.collectAsList().get(0).getDouble(0);
double validation_point = (double) ratios.collectAsList().get(0).getDouble(1);
```

but it gives me below exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Does anyone know how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to get 2 arrays, when you only have one